# Two questions are about past perfect

Tags: past-perfect, exam-questions, past-vs-past-perfect

There are 2 questions which the answer key says I'm wrong.

First:

> By the time **he was applying** / **he'd applied**, the job had already gone.

I think it should be "he was applying"

Second:

> She left before anyone **had had** / **was having** a chance to explain the situation.

I think the most suitable one is "was having", but answer key says the other one.

If truly I am wrong, could you explain why ?

[image: screenshot of the text of the first question]

[image: screenshot of the text of the second question]

Comment: *was having* is not correct since *have* is a state verb. In this case *have* indicates a possession so by dismiss, *had had* is the correct tense. Now, why do you think that the past perfect in the second sentence is incorrect?

Comment: @Ustanak Because the second part of the sentence happened after the first part ,so **in my knowledge** if it was like "She had left before anyone had a chance ..." , it would be correct but it is the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some reason to dispute the first one, but with the second, no dialect  but Indian English tends to use the continuous nowadays with *having* when the reference is to an action that occurs at a point in time or with reference to a present condition or with accumulated experience.

CONTINUOUS OVER A PERIOD OF TIME
I *am having* a hard time *getting used to* life in a rural village, after *having grown up* in New York City.

DISCRETE ACTION AT A POINT IN TIME
The CEO had left for another meeting before I *had* a chance to explain the numbers on the report.  [The CEO was already gone when I explained the numbers to the other attendees at the meeting.]

or with the past-perfect

The CEO left for another meeting before I *had had* a chance to explain the numbers on the report to him.  [I did not get a chance to explain the numbers to the CEO]

or with the simple past

The CEO left for another meeting before I *had* a chance to explain the numbers on the report to him.  [I did not get a chance to explain the numbers to the CEO]

A **chance** is perceived to be a *momentary occurrence*, not a prolonged period of opportunity.

<sup>OK</sup> Here she comes. Now's your *chance to ask* her to the spring dance.

<sup>not OK</sup> Here she comes. Now's your *chance to be asking* her to the spring dance.

Comment: But the second sentence in my question , the first part of the sentence is past simple ,so is the usage still correct ?

Comment: See my addendum about **chance** and the non-continuous.

Comment: I have placed a paraphrase of the meaning inside [square brackets].

Comment: One last question , when I studied past perfect , there was just a one usage ,which is "emphasise one action happened before another in the past".Is this usage begin used advance english or it is the same usage ,but I couldn't figure out ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Ok let me ask another way , What is the general explanation for this usage (DISCRETE ACTION AT A POINT IN TIME) .I mean I am taught that past perfect is used for emphasising one action happened before another in the past ,but this usage not fit with it , so what is the general explanation for this usage.

Comment: Although your examples involved the past perfect, your original question actually related to the *continuous*, since you wanted to know about "was applying" and "was having".  I was trying to show you when the continuous would or wouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: the past perfect is formed by:
**Had** + **past participle**

---

For the first sentence, you should try to think about it like this: 
He tryied to apply for the job, (he **filled** the application form), but the job was already taken: so the verb refers to a finished action.

Was applying could be used if he started to apply *but was stopped*:

> *While* he was applying a woman asked him a question.

---

The second statement should be easier, but again think about it like an action that didn't happened: the phrase **it's not about something that was in progress**, so again there's no use of the Past Continuous form. You can read more about it [here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html).

Comment: So you are saying that he/she intended to apply to the job ,but the job had already taken , right ?

Comment: Not exactly: he intended to apply and he also applied, meaning that he gave his CV to the company. Sadly the job was already taken, but he still tried. That's correct even if he was rejected right away, or if wasn't called back, or if he was called back a week later.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your english study.